# How do I import and configure an LLM so that auto device_map='auto' is supported or circumvented?

Tags: python, large-language-model

I'm trying to import and LLM to train over medical data, but I keep recieiving the following error:

> ValueError: BertLMHeadModel does not support `device_map='auto'`. To implement support, the model class needs to implement the `_no_split_modules` attribute.

Here is how I am importing and configuring the LLM

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

# Choose a model appropriate for your task
model_name = "emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Set device manually
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# Load the model and move it to the selected device
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=2)
model.to(device)

# Move inputs to the same device
inputs = tokenizer("Your clinical note here", return_tensors="pt")
inputs = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in inputs.items()}

# Inference
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs)

df['num_characters_input'] = df['input'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

model = None
clear_cache()
df_train = df
qlora_fine_tuning_config = yaml.safe_load(
"""
model_type: llm
base_model: emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT

input_features:
  - name: instruction
    type: text

output_features:
  - name: output
    type: text

prompt:
  template: >-
    Below is an instruction that describes a task, paired with an input
    that may provide further context. Write a response that appropriately
    completes the request.

    ### Instruction: {instruction}

    ### Input: {input}

    ### Response:

generation:
  temperature: .1
  max_new_tokens: 10

adapter:
  type: lora
  r: 8

quantization:
  bits: 8

trainer:
  type: finetune
  epochs: 4
  batch_size: 16
  eval_batch_size: 16
  gradient_accumulation_steps: 16
  learning_rate: 0.00001
  optimizer:
    type: adam
    params:
      eps: 1.e-8
      betas:
        - 0.9
        - 0.999
      weight_decay: 0
  learning_rate_scheduler:
    warmup_fraction: 0.06
    reduce_on_plateau: 1
"""
)


model = LudwigModel(config=qlora_fine_tuning_config, logging_level=logging.INFO)

results = model.train(dataset=df_train)
```

I would greatly appreciate some advice on how I can resolve this. For context I am running this on google collab T4 GPU.

To resolve the error, I tried to manually specify the device to use in each step, as you can tell from the code. I also tried using many other LLMs, and I ran into the same issue.